# Return data from for loop without return statement

Tags: python, flask

I have got a list of 1000 meals. I want to fetch the top 10 meals by calling an API. The API runs through an algorithm. The algorithm is slow and it takes time to do the calculation on all 1000 meals. So to minimize the time, the algorithms create a CSV file in chunks of the top 100 meals (i.e 10 CSV files for 1000 meals) and merge it all in the end with 1000 meals into a single merge_All.csv.

So here how the API should work from the client-side.

1. The client called an API for the first time. The API starts the algorithm and will create the 1st CSV chunk and return the result to the client from the 1st CSV. I.e (Top 10 from 1-100 meals)
2. Now, the Client is not satisfied with the result. It calls the API again. Now the API should return the Top 10 meals from the 2nd CSV generated. I.e (Top 10 from 100-200 meals).
3. There might be a case where the client waits for some time to get better results, in the meantime the
   API might have created a 7th CSV file. So when clients call API it should return the top 10 meals from the 7th CSV. (i.e 600-700 meals).
4. If the API has generated merge_All.csv. Then the client should get the top 10 users from that CSV at calling time.

The solution I am looking for is:

I want to keep this for loop inside 'evaluate_combinations' running till it generates all temp CSV files and final CSV file, and at the same time return the first 'possible_food_list_temp' so that I can read the first temp CSV file data in API method and return data to the user, Currently, the problem is 'evaluate_combinations' is returning only first temp list and generating only one CSV file which is wrong, instead, it should run till all combination count in for loop and generate more than 1 temporary CSV file
I have tried with yield method but it requires a while loop.

Code Extract for better understanding:

```
def evaluate_combinations(...params)
    for c in combinations:
        if loop_cnt % iter_limit == 0 or loop_cnt == total_comb:
            possible_food_list += possible_food_list_temp
            # This method generate_food method do some calculation and creates a CSV file with a bunch of data
 
            generate_food(possible_food_list_temp,  choice, N, item_ids, items)
            
            if len(possible_food_list_temp) > 0: 
                return possible_food_list_temp
                print('\nTemporary output generated!')
            else:
                print('\nOutput not generated. Trying other combinations...')
 
            possible_food_list_temp = []
 
    return possible_food_list
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the partial results, 1st CSV, 2nd CSV and so on.

Comment: yield instead of returning; add to the list instead of making a new one; in the calling code, keep track of how many items were yielded on the last iteration so it can *proceed* with the new stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You described your structural error quite neatly, but didn't recognize it:

> I want to keep this for loop inside 'evaluate_combinations' running
> till it generates all temp CSV files and final CSV file, **and at the
> same time** return the first 'possible_food_list_temp'...

You expect your module to carry out two different executions at the same time.  This requires multi-processing / multi-threading.  Your code does not include any such attempt.

It's time to do a little more research.  Work through the tutorials and examples, starting with subprocesses.  Spawn a child process to do your 100-meal chunking and make its results available.  You may want another process to accumulate the results and keep them available on request.  Your function's purpose no reduces to grabbing the latest CSV and reporting back to the caller.

Does that get you moving?